# How to export faces of a person instead of original photo?

Tags: macos, photos.app

In Photos.app, when looking at all pictures of a person, it is possible to switch the view from showing the photo to showing the face of a person detected.

[image: View switched to Faces]

Is it possible to export cropped pictures with just the face instead of original? If yes, how?